# how to change calendar language by clicking on options using jquery.

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Greetings i am using jquery-ui datepicker, I've read numbers of solution that gave me some idea of how it works, but i am struggling with something here, i have this select tag:

```
<select id="LanguageDropDownList" name="lang">
    <option value="en-GB" selected="selected" style="text-align: center">English (en-GB)</option>
    <option value="fa" style="text-align: center">فارسی</option>
    <option value="ar" style="text-align: center">العربی</option>
</select>
```

whenever an option is selected this jquery function is called:

```
    $('#LanguageDropDownList').change(function() {

        var langSelected = $('#LanguageDropDownList option:selected').val();

        switch (langSelected) {
            case 'en-GB':
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);
                break;
            case 'fa':
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fa']);
                break;
            case 'ar':
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ar']);
                break;
        }
    });
```

and I've included the language script packages which are [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n) and it works, but the problem starts when i call that jquery function i made, datepicker wont change instantly when i select an option. but when i write for example:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['ar']);
```

out of that switch statement it works.. can i write `Setdefaults` in my switch cases? or do i have to use something else instead to change the datepicker formats?

Comment: try to initialize your datepicker element after you select the language in drop down

Comment: can u provide a snippet or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize the datepicker element after you set the defaults.
eg;

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fa']);
$( "#your_element_ID" ).datepicker({});
```

Comment: try to initialize your datepicker element after you select the language in drop down

Comment: it works for the first time i use it, is there any way that i can achieve changing that datepicker without a submit occurs?

Comment: you have to change it in the switch. there is no other way i know of.

Comment: i managed to get this working, initializing it certainly helped.

Comment: yes it certainly does, i came across the same problem few days ago. this solution worked